# Exception thrown during the rendering of a template("Parameter "id" for route "url" must match "[^/]++" ("" given) to generate a corresponding URL.")

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony4

I have a delete button which is created here:

**_delete_form.html.twig**

```
<form method="post" action="{{ path('finals_delete', {'id': final.id}) }}" onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?');">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token('delete' ~ final.id) }}">
<button class="btn btn-success" style="margin-top: 10px">Verwijderen</button>
```

I include it in **Edit** page like so:

```
   {{ include('finals/_form.html.twig', {'button_label': 'Opslaan'}) }}

    <button class="btn btn-success"><a href="{{ path('finals_index') }}">Terug naar lijst</a>  </button>

   {{ include('finals/_delete_form.html.twig') }}
```

The controller action for **Delete:**

```
    /**
 * @Route("/{id}", name="finals_delete", methods={"POST"})
 */
public function delete(Request $request, Finals $final): Response
{
    if ($this->isCsrfTokenValid('delete'.$final->getId(), $request->request->get('_token'))) {
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->remove($final);
        $entityManager->flush();
    }

    return $this->redirectToRoute('finals_index');
}
```

The controller action for **edit:**

```
/**
 * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="finals_edit", methods={"GET","POST"})
 */
public function edit(Request $request, Finals $final): Response
{
    $final = new Finals();
    $form = $this->createForm(FinalsType::class, $final);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    $imageFile = $form->get('imageTeam1')->getData();

    //If function to only process an imagine if its uploaded
    if ($imageFile) {

        $originalFilename = pathinfo($imageFile->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME);

        //Remove unwanted characters from filename
        $safeFilename = transliterator_transliterate('Any-Latin; Latin-ASCII; [^A-Za-z0-9_] remove; Lower()', $originalFilename);
        $newFilename = $safeFilename.'-'.uniqid().'.'.$imageFile->guessExtension();


        //Move file to image dir
        try {
            $imageFile->move($this->getParameter('images_directory'),$newFilename);
        }   catch (FileException $e) {
            $this->addFlash('danger', 'Er is iets fout gegaan probeer het opnieuw');
        }

        $final->setImageTeam1($newFilename);


        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
        return $this->redirectToRoute('finals_index');
    }

    return $this->render('finals/edit.html.twig', [
        'final' => $final,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

All this was created using the bin/console make:crud command, I have made multiple pages like this with the exact same button and code but only this one for some reason gives this error:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Parameter "id" for route "finals_delete" must match "[^/]++" ("" given) to generate a corresponding URL.").
```

*in C:\xampp\htdocs\Freulepartij\templates\finals_delete_form.html.twig (line 1)*

It throw's the error as soon as I click my edit page(when the delete button is just being rendered and the function behind it not executed?) which I find strange. When I remove the include I can get in my edit page but
My edit form won't update the record either so it just doesn't know what to do with the data?
I am really confused because the id is right in the url when I click my edit page without the delete button

**UPDATE 1**

As Gary Houbre suggested I replaced

```
 {{ include('finals/_delete_form.html.twig' }}
```

with

```
{{ include('finals/_delete_form.html.twig' , {'final': final.id}) }}
```

And now get this error :

> Impossible to access an attribute ("id") on a null variable.

But I am looking in my database and only have 2 records in this table both have id's so I dont know how it is getting a null value?

**UPDATE 2**

I found this in the symfony logs which confirms the right id "7"
So thats leaving me with even more confusion..

> SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.team1 AS team1_2, t0.team2 AS team2_3,
> t0.image_team1 AS image_team1_4, t0.image_team2 AS image_team2_5,
> t0.paragraph AS paragraph_6, t0.eersten_p1 AS eersten_p1_7,
> t0.eersten_p2 AS eersten_p2_8, t0.punten_p1 AS punten_p1_9,
> t0.punten_p2 AS punten_p2_10 FROM finals t0 WHERE t0.id = ?
>
> [
> "7" ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in gary's comments i had a new call in a edit function which obviously does not belong there so thats where my problem was

Answer (score 0):

Into your edit.html.twig, the line where your include file _delete.html.twig

Your need add parameter 'id'.
For example :

```
{% include 'template.html' with {'foo': 'bar'} %}
```

I follow this documentation Twig in this [link](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/include.html)

Comment: I tried this and it did not change anything, stil the same error

Comment: Your include with {'final': 'final'} right ?

Comment: When I replace that with {'final': final.id} i get : Impossible to access an attribute ("id") on a null variable.

Comment: Try this : {{ include('finals/_delete_form.html.twig' , {'final': final}) }}

Comment: I tried but that gives me the original error

Comment: I think find your problem : $final = new Finals(); in your edit function. You don't need to add him because you have got a Finals object before.